Missing partition on disk utility for Mac. How to find it and revert it back to Mac?
A while back, I partitioned my Mac SSD, but never got around to installing an OS. Now when I go to disk utility, I cannot find the partition. Has anyone faced this before and what can I do?
There is only one drive being shown under internal and that's my current Mac Install.
I tried using disk Utility to find the other partition, but only one drive is being shown under internal and that's the Mac install I'm running.
When running diskutil list, I'm receiving this output:
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         121.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Untitled - Data⁩         84.0 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 427.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      6.4 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Untitled⁩                15.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s5s1

However, in Disk Utility, I am only seeing this partition:


Do you have "Show All Devices" selected under the View menu? Also, what does the Terminal command diskutil list show?

@GordonDavisson /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         121.1 GB   disk0s2
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
Physical Store disk0s2

first off thanks for showing I can still see it. Wasn't able to find it anywhere else.. but how can I access it now and either bring it back into Mac or install something like linux on it?

It sounds like your partition is an empty APFS container (i.e. with no volumes in it). Does the disk itself show up in Disk Utility? If so, just select that and erase the entire disk (creating whatever type of volume and partition scheme you want). BTW, it'd be much clearer to edit the question to add info like the diskutil output  (using code block format, so the text layout displays accurately).

unfortunately, it is not showing up under diskutil. Diskutil only shows the corresponding disk for
/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +121.1 GB   disk1
Physical Store disk0s2
@GordonDavisson

I edited the post to show the output for diskutil list and a screenshot of disk utility

This looks normal for the entire disk being devoted to a standard install of macOS (though the volume name, "Untitled", is unusual). Is there supposed to be another partition besides that? If so, it either got deleted at some point or never got created in the first place. The container for "Untitled" takes up the entire disk (other than the small EFI partition, which is standard on GPT-formatted disks).

Yeah, it was originally 256 GB and I split it in half. The problem is I'm only able to see the one partition in Disk Utility. There is basically half my storage that I can't see. Maybe it not showing up even with 'diskutil list'. Is there any way to access the storage that doesnt have an OS on it?

Are you sure it was originally 256GB? That part number, SM0128G, indicates a 128GB drive (see e.g. here). It might've been originally spliced together with a hard disk to make a bigger combined "fusion" drive (as in this situation), but I'd expect that to have been even bigger than 256GB.

Absolutely positive it was 256GB. I remember when I made the original partition, I could see both of them also

Then I'm stumped why it'd be showing up as a 128GB drive. This isn't just a partitioning issue, something weirder is going on. Can you check how the System Information utility (hold the Option key while choosing Apple menu > System Information) sees it. Select Hardware -> interface type (probably PCI or NVMExpress) to see it.

Oddly enough, there is nothing for either PCI or NVMExpress. When I go to storage, it shows the same 121 GB. Same thing under SATA 121.33 GB. I think you might be right about a fusion drive breaking since 121.33 seems to be the common theme whenever that happens.

I tried using diskutil resetFusion in recovery mode, but it cant even detect the other drive so it didn't do anything. Might just be some aberrant hardware failure
